# Filebeat not sending data to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, elk

I've installed elasticsearch 8.5 and Kibana 8.5 in my kubernetes cluster simply applying the official helm file in the elastic repo.
Now I'm trying to install filebeat with the following conf:

```
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
      - "/var/log/app.log"
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            in_cluster: true
```

and

```
output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
      protocol: https
      ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/usr/share/filebeat/certs/ca.crt"]
```

Our apps are writing logs in pod container under /var/log/app.log but it seems filebeat does not read the log or not send it to elasticsearch because no index are created in elastic.

How can I solve the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the logs of your filebeat pods, did you `kubectl describe pod` them ? Is the elastic cluster up up and running ?

Comment: Filebeat pods are up and running (12 replicas). Elastic is up and running (3 master nodes). The only error I see in filebeat logs regards a parsing date error in read event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working config (Paths etc. needs adaption)

```
daemonset:
  extraEnvs:
    - name: "ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME"
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: elasticsearch-master-credentials
          key: username
    - name: "ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD"
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: elasticsearch-master-credentials
          key: password

filebeatConfig:
  filebeat.yml: |
    logging.metrics.enabled: false
    filebeat.inputs:
      - type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/agri-check*.log
        json:
          keys_under_root: true
          overwrite_keys: true
        processors:
          - add_kubernetes_metadata:
              host: ${NODE_NAME}
              matchers:
                - logs_path:
                    logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
      - type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*.log
        exclude_files: ['.*/agri-check.*$']
        processors:
          - add_kubernetes_metadata:
              host: ${NODE_NAME}
              matchers:
                - logs_path:
                    logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"

    output.elasticsearch:
      host: '${NODE_NAME}'
      hosts: "https://elasticsearch-master:9200"
      username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}'
      password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}'
      protocol: https
      ssl.verification_mode: none
```

Comment: Is your app writing logs in /var/log/containers/ of the pod?

Comment: no stdout and stderr. I assume they are stored on the *host* VM in these directories

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried and this is working fine. +1